# How do you express a function, whos range is a set of functions in math notation?

Tags: functions, notation

I'm struggling to clearly express this notion. I would like to express a function of 2 variables as a successive application of 2 functions, first a function A->Fa that is mapped to a set of functions (mapping the sets B->C)

Comment: Use LaTeX please.

Comment: Sorry, if I'm having trouble expressing a simple concept like that, i'm obviously not going to go through learning LaTeX before posting a question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [*set* of functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_space#Examples) from $B$ to $C$ is denoted with $C^B$.

Thus :

> $f : A \to C^B$.